# ArrayList isEmpty() always returning true

Tags: java, arraylist

im having some issues when using the method `isEmpty()` with `ArrayList`.

I have two `ArrayLists` initialized with the values of two Arrays: `getDrivers()` and `getCars()`.

```
ArrayList<Driver> drivers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getDrivers()));
ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(getCars()));
```

I know both arrays are empty cause I havent written anything in them, so the `ArrayList`s should be emptied too, but when i execute these sentences:

```
drivers.isEmpty()) 
cars.isEmpty()
```

The result is:

```
false
false
```

for both sentences

How is it possible?

Comment: What does `getDrivers()` and `getCars()` return? I'm guessing those are the cause of your problem.

Comment: What does `getDrivers()` and `getCars()` return? If we don't tell us we cannot tell you what's wrong.

Comment: The arrays returned by `getDrivers()` and `getCars()` methods should be empty or you're calling `List#isEmpty` on different variables. Please post the relevant code to replicate the problem.

Comment: There is one closing `)` too much.

Comment: So the title of you question is “ArrayList isEmpty() always returning true” while you are complaining that they actually return `false`? That’s weird. Further, I don’t understand why you don’t look what the lists contain. `ArrayList`s are no blackboxes.

Comment: check getDrivers().length

Comment: just do `System.out.println(drivers)` and see what's in the list?

Comment: System.out.println(cars); returns [null],[null] The other one too

And why does it store null values? How can i avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that when you say "the arrays are empty," you mean that they have been created but not filled, so they are still full of nulls.  If the arrays are filled with nulls, then you're creating an ArrayList containing that many nulls.

Comment: Mate, 72k reputation and you still cannot tell the difference between answer and comment?

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski my answer describes my best guess as what is actually happening, and a question the OP can check to verify that my guess was correct.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it does answer the question; it explains why the ArrayLists would be nonempty even if the OP believed the arrays being used to initialize them were empty.

Comment: System.out.println(cars); returns [null],[null]
The other one too